# Trouble with Dividing Series in Grafana: Blank Screen Issue

Tags: grafana, dashboard, metrics, grafana-variable

I'm currently facing an issue in Grafana (datasource: Metrictank) that I'm hoping to get some guidance on. The problem occurs when I'm attempting to divide two series - 'Series B' (Total number of errors) by 'Series A' (Total count).

My query also includes a variable on which both these series (A and B) are dependent. When I try using divideSeries, divideSeriesList functions or even the mathematical expression ($B * 100 /$A), I'm presented with a blank screen.
[image]
Interestingly, if I remove the variable from the query, the division operation works just fine. However, I'm struggling to make it work when the variable is included. Any help to address this issue would be greatly appreciated!

I tried removing the variable which worked but I need to get this working with the variable in place